# Phonegap input field keyboard not showing sometime

Tags: cordova

I am working on phonegap 3.0. I have a text field to search.

Sometimes text field keyboard does not showing up when focusing on it in Android mobile.

Anybody facing this problem or any work around for this?

Thanks

Comment: are you using position:fixed in the text field css?